# Azure table with Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, azure, cloud

I'm looking for a way to manage Azure table with Silverlight 4,
can someone tell me where can I find something useful?

Answer (score 0):

The new RIA Services toolkit has a Table storage domainservice provider which would probably be what you need.
http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/12/02/ToolkitDecember2010.aspx

Alternatively heres another, slightly older example someone has put together:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Azurelight.aspx